# JSON to Not Inserted Custom Objects to Map

Tags: custom-object, map, deserialize

I have a JSON response I receive from an endpoint, it is then deserialized, and all of the objects are stored in a custom object list (stored in the list variable "scope").

I am trying to place this list of custom objects into a map, however the objects have not been inserted it, and may not be inserted, how do I accomplish this since they do not have IDs? I am thinking I could iterate through the scope objects and assign incremental values?

The error I receive (which to my understanding is because the objects haven't been inserted and they do not have IDs):

> Row with null Id at index: 0

```
Map<ID, Custom_Object__c> scopeAccountMap = new Map<ID, Custom_Object__c>(scope);

  system.debug(scopeAccountMap.keyset());

    for (ID idKey : scopeAccountMap.keyset()) {
        Customer_Account__c a = scopeAccountMap.get(idKey);
        Map<String, Object> fieldsToValue = a.getPopulatedFieldsAsMap();
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need to use a `Map` at all? The code you include here could just as well iterate over a `List`, and the fact that your data seems to lack a unique identifier militates against using a `Map`.

Comment: Good point. I wan running with somebody else's example with getting all of the fields for particular objects. 

Essentially ditch this first map, and iterate through the List with a < List.size() and create maps only for my fields piece sounds like the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the map and replace with a list as David Reed mentioned in his comment.

In your previous question([getSObject - Dynamically Referencing Object Fields from Map](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/220707/getsobject-dynamically-referencing-object-fields-from-map/220709?noredirect=1#comment334435_220709)) you are already iterating through this list of Custom Objects.

You can reference these objects with the dynamic field names with `scope[s].get(fieldName)` where fieldName is every key in your fieldToValue Map. Ex: `for (String fieldName : fieldsToValue.keySet()) {...`